# Can you swap the image components of a Flutter Rive animation during runtime?

Tags: flutter, animation, flare, rive

I am evaluating if Rive is a good solution for animations in a small flutter game project I am working on. I am really impressed with the Rive animation creation system and the flexibility of it, but can't seem to find a good example or documentation on if swapping an image of a Rive animation in the app at runtime would be possible.

An example use case would be I have a rive animation of a character swinging a sword. Can I change the sword image if the user equips a new sword, and then still use the same animation file? I know you can export the animations as binary or JSON and am open to either method if this is possible. While I know I could swap the sword in the rive editor and easily export the new system, this is not very scaleable if I need to now have an animation of the character with every type of equipment.

If there is another solution to the problem I am open to any approach that reasonably accomplishes this goal.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find anything about this? I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I never found anything yet but it looks like the new Rive 2 will have features that essentially allow this. It is still in beta right now though